# How to pass parameter of type "[MessageContract] class MyParameter" at client side while accessing WCF service without metadata proxy class

Tags: c#, wcf

I have following WCF service contract.

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface ICalculator
{
    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
    void Add(MyParameter obj);
}
```

Parameter class "MyParameter" is here.

```
[MessageContract]
public class MyParameter
{
    [MessageBodyMember(Order = 1)]
    public Stream ByteStream;
}
```

I am accessing WCF service without metadata proxy class.

How do I pass parameter of type `MyParameter` from client as class `MyParameter` when it is not recognizable at client side?

Comment: Could you please elaborate more on why you are not using proxy class on client side?